# Running Lookup tool in ModelBuilder using field that was joined in previous step

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, modelbuilder, precondition

I'm trying to generate a model (ModelBuilder in ArcMap) that calculates the Landslide Susceptibility Index with standardized inputs (Conditioning factors in raster format and dbf's with weights). The last step is the raster calculator where I basically use a weighted sum expression

```
(Slope * slope_weight + Geology * geology_weight + Aspect * aspect_weight + ...)
```

For this I need the several rasters with the class weights (each class has a different weight) and I used the Join field  tool (Input and Output join field=Value and field to be joined=weights) and the Lookup tool (Lookup field=weights from the previous join) to generate the raster layers with class weights (float) as pixel values.

The issue is that the join field is not recognized by the Lookup tool and therefore the model doesn't run. I supposed that if I set the Join field process as a precondition of the Lookup tool, the model would start running and the lookup tool would "wait" for its precondition (joined field), but that is not the case :(.

Is there anything I can do to set (in ModelBuilder) make this model run as I planned it?

[image: Print screen of the model]

Comment: Are you using the ModelBuilder of ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?

Comment: Add a screen shot to your question of how you are calling the lookup tool if that is where it is failing.

Comment: Are you saying that the model runs AND joins the dbf to your raster but stalls at the Lookup tool, or does the lookup tool run and fails to recognise the newly joined fields? Or the tool fails when you attempt the join?

Comment: The model does not run at all, delivering the following error: Lookup field does not exist. I've already tested the different submodel and ran them in model builder and everything works (although the same error alert as above appears). When I try to run the model outside ModelBuilder environment and write the name of the field that is joined into my Lookup field parameter it does not recognize the field name and does not run at all. Thanks in advance for yout help!